# Best way to build a JSON API coupled with HTML views in a Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, json, api

I've got a Rails eCommerce project communicating with an iOS app. The iOS app receives JSON data from the Rails back-end, but there's also HTML rendering when a user comes to the project from his browser. They basically call the same actions (create, destroy, update, etc.) from both sides.

`/website/my_action` → HTML rendering
`/website/my_action.json` → API

What's the best way to organize our Rails app to stay DRY and avoid messy code / code smell ? The project currently uses `respond_to` a lot but i'm wondering if we shouldn't switch to a split system with `default json` response:

`/api/v1/my_action`
`/website/my_action`

And if so, how would you do concretely?

Here's a sample of one method in the current system

```
  def get_following

    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render :json => ApiFormat.success(:followers, user.following) }
    end

  end
```

It looks fine but becomes **very** messy in some methods I prefer not to show. In short: how would you refacto the project in a more efficient way?

Comment: This is not so much a question about how to improve the code excerpt that you presented in the question. Rather, the excerpt is just a generic representative sample, and you are asking a "what is best practice?" question. Migrating from Code Review to Programmers.

Answer (score -2):

To me it seems like it would make more sense to split them with an api namespace for all the json controllers.  What did you end up doing?

Comment: This is not an answer. Please post comments in the comments section.